# Installing JavaFX 2.0 in Eclipse Juno for Mac

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, javafx-2, eclipse-juno

I'm running Mac OS X 10.6.x (Snow Leopard) right now, so I'm pretty sure that there could be some issues with supported systems, but I'm trying to install JavaFX 2.0 (or 2.1.x) in Eclipse Juno for Java EE (version 3.8).

I have already installed the e(fx)clipse plugin, but I'm not sure if I'm downloading the right JavaFX .zip file from the Oracle website. I downloaded the JavaFX 2.2 beta release because it seemed to be the only release available for OS X, but I could be wrong. Once I download this archive, I'm not exactly what to do with it/where to place it so that Eclipse recognizes it as the JavaFX 2.2 SDK. I know that I have to go into preferences and set the location of the SDK file, but there doesn't seem to be any selectable .jar file or folder to set it to. Am I doing something wrong here? Any help is appreciated.

---

Edit: I worked around the issue by setting the SDK location to the location of the downloaded JavaFX 2.2 SDK in the JavaFX section in the preferences tree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around the issue by setting the SDK location to the location of the downloaded JavaFX 2.2 SDK in the JavaFX section of the Eclipse preferences tree.

Answer (score 1):

The current GA release of the [Oracle Java SDK for Mac](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1637583.html) should include JavaFX 2.1.

You don't need a separate download of the JavaFX 2.2 developer release unless you rely on functionality or bug fixes from the 2.2 release.

The e(fx)clipse release 0.14 should be able to [detect](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2012/05/29/efxclipse-0-0-14-released/) the JavaFX installed with the Oracle Java distribution for Mac.

[Getting started tutorials for e(fx)clipse](http://tomsondev.bestsolution.at/2012/05/29/getting-started-with-efxclipse-and-javafx/).

**Update**

Happy to see that in your edit that you were able to use JavaFX 2.2 with OSX 10.6.  Richard Bair, Java Client Lead, [notes](https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?threadID=2402300):

> FWIW, there are in fact some APIs we use from Lion that aren't on Snow Leopard. Also, Apple only supports the current release of the OS - 1 (so now it would be Lion and Mountain Lion), and for deployment we needed special hooks. The thought was that it didn't make sense to support versions of the Mac OS that Apple themselves didn't support any longer.

so don't be surprised if everything doesn't quite work as expected.  10.6 is not a [certified configuration](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/supportedconfigurations-1506746.html) for JavaFX. As of June 2012, OpenJDK without a separate JavaFX download is likely not yet an alternative to OracleJDK for JavaFX development as all of JavaFX is not yet open sourced.

Comment: But the GA release of the Java SDK is for Mac OS X Lion. The installer won't work on any version lower than 10.7. Is OpenJDK a sufficient alternative? To my knowledge, that is on version 1.7